# What factors go into pushing the first layer speeds of an FDM print?

Tags: adhesion, fdm, speed

When searching for "how to increase first layer speed" and "how can I get faster first layers", the only results I get from both Google and DuckDuckGo are articles talking about printer basics.

You know the type: "make sure your bed is levelled, make sure your bed is cleaned, print the first layer slower", the articles aimed at beginners that are trying to get a print to finish.

I'm instead looking to increase the first layer speed, as I have seen several CoreXY machines being able to print the first layer at speeds clearly higher than 30mm/s.

I have a Sovol SV06 with the SV06+ hotend. So not a CoreXY... Are the faster first layers intrinsic to CoreXY? Or are there steps I can take on my SV06 to have better bed adhesion for faster first layers?

EDIT
Here's an example of what I'm talking about. A functional print being created on top of a first layer that was placed down so quickly.